# label duplicates based on different duplicate criteria

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, data-science

I'm looking for an efficient/correct way of doing this, as my current "solution" is probably none of those:

I have a table with 8 criterias for what a record could be considered to be duplicated with another record, and I want to "consolidate" all of them in a single column.
The table consist of 14083 records with the following columns:

```
 - ID (unique int id)
 - Criteria 1 (int between 100000 and 199999)
 - Criteria 2 (int between 200000 and 299999)
 - Criteria 3 (int between 300000 and 399999)
 - Criteria 4 (int between 400000 and 499999)
 - Criteria 5 (int between 500000 and 599999)
 - Criteria 6 (int between 600000 and 699999)
 - Criteria 7 (int between 700000 and 799999)
 - Criteria 8 (int between 800000 and 899999)
```

What I'm looking for is to generate a new column "final_id" (int) that has the same value for all records that share the same value for any {"Criteria 1",...,"Criteria 8"} column. So for example, a sample subset of what I have (and what I want for column "final_id") would be [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bd6MNEej20RzC8hZeSAweoM6lisMCRU0XW6MgUeYUB8/edit?usp=sharing):

```
|-------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------| -----------|------------|------------|----------|
|   ID  | Criteria 1 | Criteria 2 | Criteria 3 | Criteria 4 | Criteria 5 | Criteria 6 | Criteria 7 | Criteria 8 | final_id |
|-------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------| -----------|------------|------------|----------|
|2435209|   101867   |   216690   |   300109   |   402456   |   502283   |   606443   |   700628   |   800861   |     1    |
|2877454|   101867   |   216693   |   300109   |   402455   |   502283   |   616384   |   700628   |   800861   |     1    |
|2590860|   100611   |   201722   |   302380   |   400684   |   500651   |   622217   |   704105   |   800953   |     2    |
|2716183|   100612   |   201717   |   300176   |   400686   |   500651   |   612956   |   704105   |   800954   |     2    |
|2709486|   100612   |   233154   |   300176   |   401044   |   500965   |   612956   |   715224   |   800954   |     2    |
|2505207|   100711   |   201688   |   302346   |   400685   |   500651   |   617139   |   704105   |   801055   |     2    |
|2493516|   102410   |   224014   |   328546   |   403067   |   502851   |   622143   |   702756   |   801451   |     3    |
|2877017|   101926   |   211343   |   313658   |   402380   |   502216   |   605096   |   704326   |   801767   |     4    |
|2542161|   101927   |   211344   |   313659   |   402380   |   502216   |   617595   |   704326   |   801768   |     4    |
|2840166|   102006   |   211345   |   313660   |   402380   |   502216   |   624855   |   704326   |   801847   |     4    |
|2840153|   125294   |   211133   |   313385   |   431252   |   528961   |   612102   |   714675   |   801847   |     4    |
|  ...  |    ...     |    ...     |    ...     |    ...     |    ...     |    ...     |    ...     |    ...     |    ...   |
|-------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------| -----------|------------|------------|----------|
```

Where the first two records (ID 2435209 and 2877454) share the same value for "Criteria 1", so they are assigned the same value for "final_id" (they also share the same value for Criteria 3, 5, 7 and 8, but as long as they share it for at least one Criteria they should have the same "final_id").
Then there are the records with "final_id" = 2:

- ID 2590860 and 2716183 share Criteria 5 and 7
- ID 2590860 and 2709486 don't share any Criteria, but since they both share at least one criteria with 2716183, all three of them will have the same "final_id".

And so on...

To accomplish this, I have tried the following using Pandas in Python, which did what I wanted to with a subset of 1000 records, but is taking forever to run for the whole dataset:

```
i = 1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[index,'final_id'] != '':
        j = df.at[index,'final_id']
    else:
        j = i
        df.at[index,'final_id'] = j
    for index1, row1 in df.iterrows():
        for index2, criteria in enumerate(df.at[index,'Criterias']):
            if df.at[index1,'Criterias'][index2] == df.at[index,'Criterias'][index2]:
                if df.at[index1,'final_id'] != '':
                    j = df.at[index1,'final_id']
                    df.at[index,'final_id'] = j
                df.at[index1,'final_id'] = j
                for index3, row3 in df.iterrows():
                    for index4, criteria in enumerate(df.at[index1,'Criterias']):
                        if df.at[index3,'Criterias'][index4] == df.at[index1,'Criterias'][index4]:
                            if df.at[index3,'final_id'] != '':
                                j = df.at[index3,'final_id']
                                df.at[index1,'final_id'] = j
                            df.at[index3,'final_id'] = j
    i+=1
```

("Criterias" is just a new column that appends all criterias 1 to 8 in an array for each record).

I'm sure a good part of it is wrong or unnecessary, is there a more efficient way of doing this? It could be in Python, VBA or SQL. Maybe there's a function somewhere that I'm not aware of, but I think the algorithm should go something like this:

```
for each row in table:
    if "final_id" is blank:
        consolidate_criteria(row)
```

with consolidate_criteria(row) function being:

```
consolidate_criteria(row):
for column in row:
    for each row1 in table:
        if *Criterias_Match* and "final_id" is blank:
            consolidate_criteria(row1)
```

The full dataset is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i2VDcWmXcsGRmTCH4aJKdjL6zASAiRBpeczjJuo5_R0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What if a line contains a criterion shared with another line before but with another group in between? Said differently: can final_id contains decreasing ID in some cases?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but here is me trying: So if the first and last row share any criteria they would both have final_id = 1 and then if the penultimate row doesen't share a criteria with any other row, it would end up with a much larger final_id so yes, final_id can contain decreasing numbers as you go through the dataset.